Firebase Phone Auth woks on web but not on IOS device
I created an Ionic 8 + Capacitor + Firebase project and added the latest version of AngularFire to it.
Everything works perfectly on Desktop but when I launch on my iPhone, there is an error appears on Xcode console: [error] - ERROR {"code":"auth/internal-error","customData":{},"name":"FirebaseError"}
My app.module.ts looks like:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth())],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

I've spent a lot of time trying various things but it doesn't work. I even installed the firebase sdk from xcode (I don't know if it's really necessary) and I also configured the GoogleService-Info.plist file, but the error still persists.
Do you have any ideas how I can fix the problem ?

It might be because you did not add authentication persistence. Please see if this helps:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import {
    getAuth, 
    provideAuth, 
    indexedDBLocalPersistence 
} from '@angular/fire/auth'; // **<-- Import** 

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => { **// <-- Use**
      const auth = getAuth();
      auth.setPersistence(indexedDBLocalPersistence);
      return auth;
    }),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}



